# Is there a way to speed up this training process?

Tags: pytorch

I have 5 datasets, and I take 3 images from each dataset in one batch, so batch size is 5 * 3 = 15.

```
for batch in batches:
   for i, d in enumerate(batch):
       optimizer.zero_grad()
       r = net.forward(d)
```

I need to compute and save gradients for each dataset separately:

```
loss = loss_fn(r)
loss.backward()
for param in net.parameters():
    if param.grad is not None:
       grads[i].append(Variable(param.grad.data.clone(), requires_grad=False))
```

And then I need to do some calculations with these gradients essentialy obtaining coefficients for weighted loss:

```
scale = get_scales(grads)
optimizer.zero_grad()
for i, d in enumerate(batch):
    r = net.forward(d)
    loss_t = loss_fn(r)
    if i > 0:
       loss = loss + scale[i]*loss_t
     else:
       loss = scale[i]*loss_t
 loss.backward()
 optimizer.step()
```

So what's happening here I do 5 forward and backward passes to compute gradients, then Im calculating coefficients, then again 5 forward and backward passes, loss summation and finally optimizer step.
So amount of forward and backward passes is x2. And it takes way too long.
GPU's has limited memory, fitting only those 3 images in forward and backward pass.
This is currently only straightforward solution I came up with. Calculating gradients and throwing away graph. I could save calculations from first passes somehow? But I guess I'll be out of memory quick.

Is there some solution to speed up this process in memory restricted environment? I'm rather new to pytorch so Im asking this question in hope that I do not know something that could help here.

Full pseudo code example:

```
for batch in batches:
   for i, d in enumerate(batch):
       optimizer.zero_grad()
       r = net.forward(d)

       loss = loss_fn(r)
       loss.backward()
       for param in net.parameters():
           if param.grad is not None:
              grads[i].append(Variable(param.grad.data.clone(), requires_grad=False))

   scale = get_scales(grads)
   optimizer.zero_grad()
   for i, d in enumerate(batch):
       r = net.forward(d)
       loss_t = loss_fn(r)
       if i > 0:
          loss = loss + scale[i]*loss_t
       else:
          loss = scale[i]*loss_t
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you use the same r for computing loss_ft and loss_fn. You should be able at least to reuse last r for computing both loss_ft and loss_fn, because this doesn't require additional memory.
You can try to use retain_graph=True in backward() to retain the graph to backprop second time (though documentations suggest workaround of this flag i don't see anything else here https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.1/generated/torch.Tensor.backward.html)

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. Same loss function. I will try it.